# Best way to created strongly typed nested object that uses two "layers" of enums where all enum values are not required?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

For example

```
enum Size {
  Small: 'small'
  Medium: 'medium'
  Large: 'large'
}

enum Weekday {
  Monday: 'Monday'
  Tuesday: 'Tuesday'
  ...
}


// Only need Size.Medium and Size.Large, and anywhere from 1 to 7 Weekday entries
const mapping: { [size in Size]?: { [weekday in Weekday]? : MenuType } = {
  [Size.Medium] : { Weekday.Tuesday : <menuObject> }
  [Size.Large] : { 
    Weekday.Monday : <menuObject>
    Weekday.Friday : <menuObject>
  }
}
```

When I try to get the menu with `const menu = mapping[Size.Large][Weekday.Monday]` I get an error saying `Object is possibly undefined`.

What is the best way to create this mapping so that it is still strongly typed?

Comment: If you are saying that not all values of your `enum` are required in `mapping` then it is expected behavior that the object `mapping[Size.Large]` might be `undefined`.  You would have better results if you don't annotate a type for `mapping` and just let the type be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

As @Linda Paiste said, it is a normal behavior.

When you use the operator `?:` it says that the following key way be defined or not (undefined).

So when TypeScript go throught your `mapping` object, it is not certain that data behind `Size.Large` will be defined. That's why it raise you an error.

---

The choices that you have are :

---

Either you make every key mandatory, like :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAyglgL2FA3gKCrCBDANrqAXigHIBnHfEgGgygFlgATOSI0iZ1iGugGWwAnAObJiJXENG8AvgG40aUGwDqwYAGsm2AJ6o69APYhte8UZO7emACphgZU+xJ2Hp61ABiguE-HffK1p5RQAXHQAHZEZwG0ixVBC0AGNjMlCoHAiIuBBhAC59TGKAbTJEZFzYCoBdQpQoOmLmkoB3dS1dKCq1TVMaqEKYsDiohWaoEJl2dBb4JAA6GEpcOtRGidLezp0Fi376mVpNzBLt0wXXR101lCOmibOOi4CDxOPi+4eS+eA9rkgtw2JyefV0e2MbzuH02oJ2l3s1x0t3uJygcJePihqM+tG+vwWAhEwCBDxa53B+xuhxhjwpuyu2Np5Oe4Ne1PeD3uSVSIHSmWU7CyOTyPwqhKkJIA-AsMZTITc5EA)

```
enum Size {
  Small = 'small',
  Medium = 'medium',
  Large = 'large',
};

enum Weekday {
  Monday = 'Monday',
  Tuesday = 'Tuesday',
  Friday = 'Friday',
};

type MenuType = {};

const mapping: {
     [size in Size]: { 
         [weekday in Weekday] : MenuType;
     };
} = {
    [Size.Small]: { 
        [Weekday.Monday]: {},
        [Weekday.Tuesday]: {},
        [Weekday.Friday]: {},
    },

    [Size.Medium]: { 
        [Weekday.Monday]: {},
        [Weekday.Tuesday]: {},
        [Weekday.Friday]: {},
    },

    [Size.Large]: { 
        [Weekday.Monday]: {},
        [Weekday.Tuesday]: {},
        [Weekday.Friday]: {},
    },
};

const menu = mapping[Size.Large]?.[Weekday.Monday];
```

---

Either you deal with a potential *undefined* value, like :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAyglgL2FA3gKCrCBDANrqAXigHIBnHfEgGgygFlgATOSI0iZ1iGugGWwAnAObJiJXENG8AvgG40aUGwDqwYAGsm2AJ6o69APYhte8UZO7emACphgZU+xJ2Hp61ABiguE-HffK1p5RQAXHQAHZEZwG0ixVBC0AGNjMlCoHAiIuBBhAC59TGKAbTJEZFzYCoBdAH5ClCg6YtaSgHd1LV0oKrVNU3qoQpiwOKiFVqgQmXZ0NvgkADpGFkgaxuap0v7unSXXR10NxNpWmVoWqBLF4CWBEWATpqu23dMV40HGi9edro+AW+pyuvySqRA6UyynYWRyeRuFXuUiedSWJXeuk+lh0NTkQA)

```
enum Size {
  Small = 'small',
  Medium = 'medium',
  Large = 'large',
};

enum Weekday {
  Monday = 'Monday',
  Tuesday = 'Tuesday',
  Friday = 'Friday',
};

type MenuType = {};

const mapping: {
     [size in Size]?: { 
         [weekday in Weekday]? : MenuType;
     };
} = {
    [Size.Medium]: { 
        [Weekday.Tuesday]: {},
    },

    [Size.Large]: { 
        [Weekday.Monday]: {},
        [Weekday.Friday]: {},
    },
};

const menu = mapping[Size.Large]?.[Weekday.Monday];
```